# How do I reference another models value in ExpressJs?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have a model for employee information im using in a MEAN stack and want to reference the store name they will work at in a stores model, would the following be correct?

Employees:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var muv = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

var schema = new Schema({
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},
    empId: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    num: {type: String, required: true},
    job: {type: String, required: true},
    store: {type: Schema.Types.storeName, ref: 'Stores'},
});

schema.plugin(muv);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Message', schema);
```

Stores:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
    storeName: {type: String, required: true},
    lat: {type: String, required: true},
    long: {type: String, required: true},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Stores', schema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close!  You want to reference the ID of the store, not the name.   When Mongoose does the 'Join', it will see the ObjectID store in the `store` profile field and match it to an ObjectID in the `Stores` collection.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var muv = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

var schema = new Schema({
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},
    empId: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    num: {type: String, required: true},
    job: {type: String, required: true},
    store: {type: type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Stores'},  //Reference store ObjectId.
});

schema.plugin(muv);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Message', schema);
```

Comment: There is a typo error type: type: being entered beside store twice.